# Cannot run applets in Google Chrome or other browsers (JRE 8)

Tags: java, security, applet

I recently updated my JDK and JRE to Java 8 (The latest version). And I am having a serious problem running Java applets under JRE 8. Previously in Java 7, I used to decrease the security level of the Java Control Panel to medium. But now the latest version is not showing any medium security level option. It just have two options - `High` and `Very High`.

[image: java control panel->security]

How to run Java applets now? please provide suggestion.

Comment: Haha, some product manager at Oracle did a well job :D Just high and very high. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

> How to run Java applets now?

Get the author or deployer of the applets to sign them with a certificate issued by a Certification Authority.

Comment: I am developing a website and need the browser for experimental purpose. Remember its experiment. And I don't seem that I have any kind of certification.

Comment: You'll need to properly sign the applets (with a valid certificate) prior to deployment, so you might as well work that into the build now.